# Ordenar select por data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Como fazer para ordenar esse select por DATA?

```
(SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE de = '2' && para = '1' ORDER BY data)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE de = '1' && para = '2' ORDER BY data)
```

**Teste:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b471a/1

Comment: Já não está ordenando pela data?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Ta não.

Comment: Está sim, mas você está ordenando as duas consultas antes de uní-las. Tente primeiro fazer o `union` e depois ordenar pela data.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss atualiei nesse link para ver http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b471a/1

Comment: só não entendi pq não deixou sua query assim: SELECT * 
FROM mensagens 
WHERE 
(de = '2' AND para = '1') OR (de = '1' AND para = '2')
ORDER BY data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE de = '2' && para = '1')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE de = '1' && para = '2')
order by data
```

Comment: Obrigado Jovani.